# How to get PropertyGrid from TabPage Collection

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, tabpage, generic-collections

I created **newPropertyGrid** and add that to **newTabPage**. I save all newTabPage to lstTankTabPages(generic collections). I want to raise an event when the data changes in the property grid to change the custom control on the main form. *My question, How to get all **newPropertyGrid** from **lstTankTabPages***? Thank You.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Modules.tankQuantity; i++)
    {
        string name = string.Format("Tank{0}", i + 1);

        // create newTabPage
        TabPage newTabPage = new TabPage(name);
        newTabPage.Name = string.Format("tabPage{0}", name);

        // create newPropertyGrid 
        PropertyGrid newPropertyGrid = new PropertyGrid();
        newPropertyGrid.Name = string.Format("propertyGrid{0}", name);
        newPropertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes = new AttributeCollection(new DisplayModeAttribute("Ullage,Gross,Netto,Water,Temperature,Density,Capacity,Connection,Appearance"));
        newPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new TankInventoryCustom();

        // add newPropertyGrid to newTabPage
        newTabPage.Controls.Add(newPropertyGrid);

        // add newTabPage to tabControl
        this.tabControlTankInventory.TabPages.Add(newTabPage);

        // add newTabPage to collection
        Modules.lstTankTabPages.Add(newTabPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Modules.lstTankTabPages is a

```
List<TabPage>
```

then here is one way to get the PropertyGrids you have created in that loop

```
foreach(TabPage page in Modules.lstTankTabPages) {
    PropertyGrid newPropertyGrid = (PropertyGrid)page.Controls[0];
    // do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "OfType" to get all the PropertyGrid items

```
foreach (TabPage page in Modules.lstTankTabPages)
{
    PropertyGrid newPropertyGrid = page.Controls.OfType<PropertyGrid>().FirstOrDefault()
    if (newPropertyGrid != null)
    {
        // do something with it
    }
}
```